# Find all the combinations in SQL including duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets assume I have a table of orders

```
ID,  Products
----  ----
1     Banana
1     Apple
1     Pear
2     Apple
2     Banana
3     Banana
3     Apple
4     Banana
4     Pear
```

I need to count how many times the same products were bought. I have tried some different methods(inner joins; create a ranking and pivot the data) however the issue I have that it counts once(my results table):

```
Combination,           Total
------                 -----
Banana, Apple, Pear      1
Apple, Banana            2
Banana, Pear             1
```

This should be enough when we have a small list of orders, however when the list contains thousands of rows it becomes quite hard to look into these results. Assume I only care to see combinations which contains Banana. If I order the list, the combination of 'Apple, Banana' will still be somewhere not near to the list where Banana was mentioned first in the combination.

So I need to see results for each product to be first in combination list(I don't care about duplicates). So the result table should look like this:

```
Combination,           Total
------                 -----
Apple, Banana, Pear      1
Apple, Banana            2
Banana, Apple, Pear      1
Banana, Apple            2
Banana, Pear             1
Pear, Apple, Banana      1
Pear, Banana             1
```

Notes: Combinations can be split in different columns or separated by symbol.
If the combination consist of 3 or more products, ordering after the first product doesn't matter.

Comment: Looks like a homework, am i right?  what did you try first?

Comment: It is for my job, a request from the client. At first I tried to pivot the data to columns(https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=40dd8244d2af53e0fe8d383a2a62b360), and then put this into BI tool, where I can make a sum of these combinations. However, it is not enough as the client wants to see combinations for each product. Then I tried the similar solution as Gordon offered, but it displays the same view of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string_agg()` and two levels of aggregation:

```
select products, count(*) as num_orders
from (select id,
             string_agg(product, ', ') within group (order by product) as products
      from orders o
      group by id
     ) o
group by products;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ba71db3ac4bbc329e50e105e1cf611ee) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have tried this but its not quite what I need. Duplicates should also be visible (can you look at the last table in my first post?)

Comment: @Smopsi . . . Your orders have no duplicate products.  This answers the question that you have asked here.